# Malibu landscape lights flickering/strobing

Tags: electrical

I have a 12v 150 watt Malibu landscape transformer with photocell and 14 lamps of 5 watt bulbs each. This is an older system and the bulbs are not LED.  The first light starts about 6’ from the transformer and the length of wire probably goes for about 30’ - 40’ around my landscape plants and sidewalk. It has worked perfectly on Dusk to Dawn setting for quite a few years.  Now, all of a sudden, the bulbs go on and off about every 30 seconds at dusk.  They won’t kick in like they always did before.  I checked the plug and outlet to make sure it was properly plugged in and it was.  I have not yet checked the bulbs in each spotlight to ensure they are all tight and making contact with the metal part at bottom of socket for good contact.  I don’t know the gauge of the wire.  I know it is old and I should upgrade and was thinking of getting a 200 watt transformer but not sure if that is the solution.  I am a 75-year old woman and know nothing about such things. I miss my night lighting around my walk and front door.  What should I do?  Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Am I correct that the transformer is plugged into the regular electric system of the house and that the photocell detects if it is day or night? Does the on-off behavior of the lights only happen when it starts to become dark or also when it is fully dark (e.g. in the middle of the night or when you cover the light sensor with something that doesn't let light through)?

Comment: If all the bulbs are doing the same thing, you have a problem at the transformer, I'm suspecting a bad photocell, which may be replaceable, depending upon your specific models of equipment.  If you can, a few pics always help.

Comment: Try unscrewing a few bulbs (enough to make them turn off) and see if that cures it.  It may simply be overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Connect an additional light to the 120V side and when the lights start flickering does the added light flicker,  if so you have a problem with your electrical wiring, if not you may have a bad connection in the low voltage system at the transformer or first light. It is also possible its light sensor has failed and you should replace it or if needed the transformer with the light sensor. If it is the electrical wiring do you have a switch that can turn this on and off? If so listen to it closely and see if it makes any noise, if so turn it off and call an electrician, you most likely have a bad switch or a broken wire. At this point you need to call an electrician as we know your source is failing and the fault is not obvious. Please let us know how you do with this.

Comment: Sorry I approved that edit from the queue, and I mis-read what was being edited.  The image makes little sense in this answer.  Flagging for a mod to roll-back, or @gil can do it too I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You have a grand total of 70w in the lights do your 150w transformer should be plenty. It sounds like an electronics problem to me. Incandescent lamps do not have this problem and transformers also do not have this problem but an electronic dusk to dawn sensor yes it may have this problem with age the LDR light dependent resistor or solid state switch with a light sensor on the gate both could cause the strobing, replacing the dusk to Dawn sensor will be the most probable fix.

Comment: It’s (14 ) halogen bulbs at 10w each in 150w transformer.  I unplugged it, called an electrician and bought a 200w transformer to replace this old one.  Thank you everyone for your concern and comments.

Comment: Sheri the question clearly states 14 lamps at 5w each. Halogen or incandescent won’t matter they are not solid state driven lamps like LED’s or cfl’s that are known to flicker.  please update the question, the loading on the transformer will not cause strobing. As an electrician I can tell you you are wasting $. If you call the entire assembly a transformer you are spending more than needed because it is the control that is failing.